# C# WPF preview in IDE is different than while debugging

Tags: c#, wpf, label, blend

I have a Label in a Grid and inside defined the fontsize, however, I have a global style defined for all labels in a dictionary. In the preview in Blend it looks fine and the fontsize is 10 and fontweight is normal but when I debug the program the fontsize is 17 and fontweight is medium. Even if I try to change fontsize and fontweight while the application is running no chnage is visible. Why is that happening and how can i avoid it?

edit: Even is I remove the setters from the dictionary there is no change so it can't be the problem. Also i added a app.manifest with DPI Awareness set to true and nothing changed.

Label: `<Label Content="0" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="10"/>`

Dictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type Label}" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#C7C7C7"/>
                   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="17"/>
                   <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium"/>
              </Style>
```

Preview:

 [image: Preview]

Debug: 

[image: Debug]

Comment: looks like style override while you debug. you have a setter in your style saying `FontStyle ` to be 17

Comment: I know that I have this setter, but why is it suddenly happening? It worked many many times before and just for this label it won't work.

Comment: And eventhough, why should it be displayed as I want in the preview but not while debugging?

Comment: HDPI problem?  I am not so sure

Comment: I read that on the newer .NET frameworks, there are some fixes regarding the DPI awareness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I know, it's strange to answer your own question, but I fianlly found it!)
Global styles for **textblocks also affect labels.** 
I wasn't aware of it, so I didn't added information about it. Anyway, thanks for help.